# Why do I have to Smart Publish so often to correct issues?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-media-library

On a regular basis I run in to content issues within our Sitecore websites. Today's example was an image that was newly added to the media library by a content editor. They ran an incremental publish and the content item worked, but the image did not. A Smart Publish fixed this issue.

At this point I Smart Publish any time I run in to a minor issue because it fixes my issue so often.

I'm wondering if this is normal behavior. I'm concerned that we have some kind of larger potential database issue.

**Why would an Incremental Publish not fix an issue when a Smart Publish does fix an issue?**

Comment: Have you tried to incremental publishes after each other? It might be related to caching rather than publishing. If it is related to publishing, you might want to check out the publish queue in the Sitecore master database to check if the item is added to the queue.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is an issue in general. Incremental Publish works with the publish queue, and there are a number of cases when the publish queue doesn't get filled with all changed items. This happens when you change something in template, IIRC. The Smart Publish only respects the revision of an item. If it has changed, the item gets published - very simple rule. That's why it picks a number of things the Incremental Publish does not.

The docs about Publish on SDN should contain more details around it.